# How to pass a static const char as parameter to a function?

Tags: c++

I have a function which gets executed multiple times and I only want the variables to declare once, the first time it is run, as there is a whole list of variables to check against so I used `static const` to declare these variables in the function.

I would like to pass one of the `static const char` arrays to a function being called from within this function. I tried to use pointers and pass by reference but I constantly get incompatible argument type errors, saying `const char *` is incompatible with the parameter.

How do I pass a static const char array to function? It doesn't make sense for me to declare them within the function since it's a list and this function should only check against one of them, which is easily done when it is passed as parameter.

Function 1:

```
void searchFunc(int numOfBytes, char msgtxt[]) {

    static const char msg1[] = { 0x11, 0xFF };                            
    static const char msg1resp[] = { 0x0066, 0x03, 0xFF, 0x55, 0x00, 0x83 };

    static const char msg2[] = { 0x03, 0x00, 0x6A };                     
    static const char msg2resp[] = { 0x00, 0x05, 0x42, 0x1A, 0x80, 0x5A };

    if (num == 5) {
        respond(msgtxt, 2, 4, msg1, msg1resp); 
    } else if (num == 6) {
        respond(msgtxt, 2, 5, msg2, msg2resp); 
    }
}
```

Function 2 definition with error:

```
void respond(char msgtxt[], int startArr, int endArr, char commandmsg[], char responsemsg[]);
```

Argument of type "const char*" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"

Comment: For initialization that should only happen *once*, you can use a local `static` instance of an object, whose constructor does the once-only initialization. Or use something like [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once).

Comment: As for your specific question, it doesn't matter if a variable is `static` or not, you pass it to functions the same way as any other variable.

Comment: Perhaps the best edit would be one that adds a [mcve] exhibiting the problems you have, and also add the actual errors you get (in full and complete)? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Perhaps your function requires a `char*` and not a `const char*`?

Comment: Add const, as in `void respond(const char msgtxt[], ...`  `get incompatible argument type errors, saying const char * is incompatible with the parameter.` please post the _exact_ error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass a `const` pointer to a function taking a pointer.

```
static const char msg1[] = { 0x11, 0xFF };
```

declares `msg1` to be a `const char*`, but `respond()` takes a `char msgtxt[]`, i.e. a `char*` as argument.

So, for this to work, your `respond` function should have the signature

```
void respond(const char*, int, int, const char*, const char*);
```

As a general rule: references and pointers to objects that are not modified should be `const`. This also applies to your `searchFunc()`:

```
void searchFunc(int numOfBytes, const char*msgtxt) { ... }
```